# javascript: open url and show hidden div

Tags: javascript

I would like to achieve the following and would sincerely appreciate your help.

onclick of a button:

1. open destination url on same window
2. `.show()` specific  from that url

Comment: You mean, adding an iframe  with the url in it and then pulling a div out of that iframe and displaying it in the main window?

Comment: Hi PitaJ, no, not by an iframe. The scenario would look like this: 1. user clicks on a button 2. user is taken to a new page on a website (open "_self") 3. the new page displays the <div class="show_rewards"> that the user is looking for while hiding all other <div>s on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have control over the destination url, you can pass, as a query, the id of the div that you wish to show and then fetch that id onLoad and display it.

```
self.location = "nextPage.html?div=foo";

//nextPage.html

document.onload = function(){
  if(self.location.search.indexOf("div=") == 0){
       document.getElementById(
         self.location.search.substring(4)).style.visibility = "visible";
   }
}

//nextPage.html body...
<div id="foo" style="visibility:hidden">
```

If you don't have control over the destination url then there's nothing you can do.

Oh and welcome to Stack! :) if you find answers useful make sure to up-vote them and mark them correct.

Comment: Hi Dr. Dredel, I do have control over the destination url but that page is set up to .show() or .hide() each <div> based on the users search criteria. Is there a way to get to this page "onclick" and only show a specific <div>? Many thanks again.

Comment: yeah, my example does exactly what you're asking. In this case you have a div whose id is "foo" and you pass on the query that this is the div you want to show, and you show it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show a div, you could try
     a href="" onClick="document.getElementById('div').visibility='visible'

Comment: Hi Waffle Face :), I actually would like to do two things: 1. goto the destination url. 2. on the destination url, show a specific <div>...

Comment: Then you probably should do as Dr.Dredel suggests but just store the name of the div until the click happens.